# Why is the first user input ignored when entering string input?

Tags: java, string, input

```
if((type.toLowerCase()).equals("phone number")) {                                   
    System.out.println("Enter phone number: ");
    kb.nextLine();
    individual.setPhoneNumber(kb.nextLine());
}
```

Basically if the user enters a phone number the first time, it is ignored. The user must then re-enter the information for the string and it will work the second time.

For an identical piece of code in which an integer is enterred, however, it works on the first input.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint

Comment: I think we need some more info. For example, what type is kd variable? Other than that, Why do you call kd.nextLine() once first (ignoring the return value) before setting the value from the second call?

Comment: How did you format this? By having your dog/cat sit on the keyboard??

Comment: Terrible code formatting -- fixed. Please next time fix it before posting it. You're asking volunteers to help, so you should strive to make it easy for them to do so.

Comment: What did you expect this line `kb.nextLine();` to do?

Comment: You're asking the user for input, ignore the entered data and then you're asking for more input, which you're using then. And know you don't know why the user have to input the data twice?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to call nextLine() again as a parameter?

```
if((type.toLowerCase()).equals("phone number")){                                    
    System.out.println("Enter phone number: ");
    String number = kb.nextLine();
    individual.setPhoneNumber(number);
}
```